# Signal multiple TimeSpan

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signals

I have an application that uses SignalR, in which I have defined a timeSpan which every 10 seconds will verify the changes in a database.

Taking advantage of the fact that I have the connection open, I want to verify another type of information every 10 minutes.

Do you know if another timespan can be added or is it correct to do this?
Can someone guide me on how to fix this?

I attach my code

```
private readonly static Lazy<Ticker> _instance = new Lazy<StockTicker>(() => new StockTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTicker>().Clients));

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Operator> _operators = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Operator>();

        private readonly object _updateLock = new object();

        private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        private readonly Random _updateOrNotRandom = new Random();

        private readonly Timer _timer;

        private Ticker(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
        {
            Clients = clients;

            var operators = new List<Operator>
            {
                new Operator {}
            };

            operators.ForEach(stock => _operators.TryAdd("", stock));
            _timer = new Timer(UpdatePrices, null, _updateInterval, _updateInterval);

        }
```

I want to be verifying information every 10 seconds and apart every 10 minutes.

Comment: You can write a Background service that would accomplish your task.